# how do I create a simple login/account system?

Tags: java, authentication, system, account

(Input) Username. Password Billy. 1234 Tony. 5653

(Output) What's the user name ? Billy What's the password 1234 Access granted

How would I create a input data that will have a user name and password,then how would I get it to reset screen and say (welcome "Username")

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer for this question is to go throw a *simple java input/output program*, just google it. However, I would recommend you to check [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2853/Java-Basics-Input-and-Output) tutorial.

From [that](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2853/Java-Basics-Input-and-Output) tutorial - lesson - the following code will fulfill your request:

```
    import java.io.* ;
    class Tut1 {
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
               InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(System.in) ;
               BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(istream) ;

               System.out.println("Welcome To My First Java Program");
          try {
               System.out.println("What is the username?");
               String username= bufRead.readLine();

               System.out.println("What is the password?");
               String password = bufRead.readLine();

               //if(username.equal("**") && password.equal("**")){

               System.out.println("Access Granted");

               //To clear screen
               System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
               System.out.flush();

               System.out.println("Welcome\""+ username +"\"");

               //}
          }
          catch (IOException err) {
               System.out.println("Error reading line");
          }
     }  
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for one that uses a notepad or wordpad, that has a username and password on it and it scans for them ,and if input on keybord it right (outputs )""Username name and password correct" so they also have there own basic file that's hidden